# Typescript error TS2420 : Class incorrectly implements interface

Tags: typescript

Upon building my app , I get the following error, which seems strange to me as the property appName is stated :

> ERROR in ../src/app/app.service.ts (30,14): Class 'AppService'
> incorrectly implements interface 'InternalStateType'.   Property
> 'appName' is missing in type 'AppService'.)

app.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

interface InternalStateType {
  [key: string]: any;
  appName: string;
  darkMode: boolean;
  defaultLang: string;
  topnavTitle: string;
  messagePanelOpen: boolean;
  sidenavOpen: boolean;
  sidenavMode: string;
  sidenavCollapse: boolean;
  pageFullscreen: boolean;
  pageFooter: boolean;
  initial: boolean
};


/**
 * App service
 */
@Injectable()
export class AppService implements InternalStateType {

  // Set your states default value.
  private state: InternalStateType = {
    appName: 'MyApp',
    darkMode: false,
    defaultLang: 'en',
    topnavTitle: 'MyApp',
    messagePanelOpen: false,
    sidenavOpen: false,
    sidenavMode: 'over',
    sidenavCollapse: true,
    pageFullscreen: false,
    pageFooter: false,
    initial: false
  };

  public cloneState(): InternalStateType {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
  }

  public reloadState(state: InternalStateType) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public getState(prop?: any): InternalStateType {
    const state = this.state;
    return state.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? state[prop] : state;
  }

  public setState(prop: string, value: any) {
    return this.state[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

Where am I wrong ? thanks for your feedback

Comment: If you want to implement that interface, you have to write all `InternalStateType` properties directly on your class.

Comment: thanks that's it...  can you reply as an answer so I can vote for it ?

Comment: of course :) I extended the answer a little bit for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

The interface you defined does only has "direct properties", but your class that should implement `InternalStateType` all properties of `InternalStateType` are members of the `state` properties.

You have to remove the `state` property from your class. Everything should work then :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually have the `appName` property on `AppService` type. Your `state` is typed as `InternalStateType` and has `appName` property. If you actually want `AppService` to implement `InternalStateType`, define it like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService implements InternalStateType {

  private appName: string;
  // ... define other members of `InternalStateType` here

}
```

If you did not intend for `AppService` to implement `InternalStateType`, remove it from the class declaration:

```
export class AppService {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback ...   as @sebastian stated , I missed the properties declaration directly in my class...